# How to insert a custom header into a table rendered with DT Shiny with code from a separate module?

Tags: css, r, shiny, module, namespaces

I'm completely new to modularizing in R Shiny using namespaces and I don't find it very intuitive. In the below code, broken into "Core App Code" and "Module Code", the reactive object `iris1` is transmitted between the Core App Code and the Module Code, for use among several functions in the Module Code. The code uses parameters in the calls to the module server functions (and to their definitions). It assigns the value returned from one module to a reactive in the main server function, and then passes that reactive to the second module via the call to its server function.

The below seems to work EXCEPT that the customer header (a second header rendered in CSS in the `myContainer` function in the Module Code) that spans several columns, appearing above the DT table headers) does not work. What am I doing wrong in the below?

**Code App Code:**

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

source("C:/Users/.../my_module.R") 

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("number", label = "Enter sepal length multiplier:", value = 1),
  DTOutput('tbl')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  iris1 <- reactive({
    tmp <- iris
    tmp$Sepal.Length <- tmp$Sepal.Length * input$number
    tmp
  })
  
  output$tbl <- renderDT({renderTable(iris1())})
  
  # Pass the reactive object iris1 to the module server function
  callModule(my_module_server, "myModule", iris1 = iris1)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Module Code (saved as *my_module.R*):**

```
myContainer <- function() {
  htmltools::withTags(table(
    class = 'display',
    thead(
      tr(
        th(style = "border-top: none;border-bottom: none;"),
        th(colspan = 4, 'Lengths and widths',
           class = "dt-center",
           style = "border-right: solid 0.5px;border-left: solid 0.5px;border-top: solid 0.5px; background-color:#E6E6E6;"
        )
      ),
      tr(
        th(),
        lapply(names(iris1()), th)  # Access iris1 reactive object
      )
    )
  ))
}

renderTable <- function(data) {
  datatable(
    data,
    container = myContainer(),
    options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
  )
}

my_module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  DTOutput(ns("tbl"))
}

my_module_server <- function(input, output, session, iris1) {
  output$tbl <- renderDT({
    renderTable(
      iris1()  # Access iris1 reactive object
    )
  })
}
```

Comment: I see only one module (with server function `my_module_server` and ui function `my_module_ui`).  Where are the other(s)?  Your `iris1` reactive is a `data.frame`.  It has no "formatting".  The formatting is associated with the rendition of the underlying object by (eg) `renderTable`, so there is no reason for your custom formatting to "transfer" with the `data.frame`.  Your code is not reproducble because we do not have access to your `C:` drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working example of a modularized code. While you added a module to your code your are actually not using it, i.e. your `tbl` output is created in the main server and only this output is included in the main UI.

Instead I added the module UI to the main UI and dropped the `output$tbl` from the main server as well as the corresponding render function. Additionally, as `myContainer` is simply a function make it self contained by passing the names for your table as an argument instead of relying on a `reactive` defined in a different part of your app. Actually, when I run your code I get an error because of this. Also, I don't see any reason to overwrite `shiny::renderTable` with a custom function. If a custom function is needed I would suggest to make this clear by using a different name. Finally, I switched to the new style modules using `moduleServer` instead of using `callModule`.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

myContainer <- function(x) {
  htmltools::withTags(table(
    class = "display",
    thead(
      tr(
        th(style = "border-top: none;border-bottom: none;"),
        th(
          colspan = 4, "Lengths and widths",
          class = "dt-center",
          style = "border-right: solid 0.5px;border-left: solid 0.5px;border-top: solid 0.5px; background-color:#E6E6E6;"
        )
      ),
      tr(
        th(),
        lapply(x, th)
      )
    )
  ))
}

my_module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  DTOutput(ns("tbl"))
}

my_module_server <- function(id, iris1) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    output$tbl <- renderDT({
      datatable(
        iris1(),
        container = myContainer(names(iris1())),
        options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
      )
    })
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("number", label = "Enter sepal length multiplier:", value = 1),
  my_module_ui("myModule")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  iris1 <- reactive({
    tmp <- iris
    tmp$Sepal.Length <- tmp$Sepal.Length * input$number
    tmp
  })

  my_module_server("myModule", iris1 = iris1)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3641
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this works well and your explanations are very helpful. I was able to separate `myContainer`, `my_module_ui`, and `my_module_server` into a separate file and source them from the main App code using `source("C:/Users/.../my_module.R")`. I am beginning to understand modules and namespaces with this simple example, thank you.